# jquery break loop onclick and continue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just working on simple gallery and want to loop an array once each time I click a button and continue upon clicking again.

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var pack_img = [
    'image1.jpg',
    'image2.jpg',
    'image3.jpg',
    'image4.jpg',
    'image5.jpg'
  ];

  $("#btn").click(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<pack_img.length; i++) {
       alert(pack_img[i]);
       return false;
     }  
  })
});
```

I've search already about breaking and continue looping, but seems so very complicated for me

Any idea is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
var _index = -1;
$("#btn").click(function(){

    if(_index < pack_img.length){
         _index ++;
    }else{
         _index = 0;
    }
    alert(pack_img[_index ]);
});
```

Comment: +1 as you don't need to use a for loop to step through an array.

Comment: Works great!!! I haven't thought that it will only require me to use if statement to meet my expectations. Thanks :)

Comment: Just an FYI: You can replace your `if` and `else` statements with `_index = (_index + 1) % pack_image.length;`

Comment: Or `_index = _index < pack_img.length ? _index + 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

you have to keep track of previous array item like this:

```
var previous = 0;
$("#btn").click(function(){

    for(var i=previous; i<pack_img.length; i++) {
       previous = i;
       alert(pack_img[i]);
       return false;
     }  

})
```

Answer (score 0):

count the click

```
var cnt = 0;
$("#btn").click(function(){

    for(var i=cnt; i<pack_img.length; i++) {
        if(i != pack_img.length-1){
            console.log(pack_img[i]);
            cnt++;
            break;
        }else{
            console.log(pack_img[i]);
            cnt = 0;
            break;
        }

     }  

})
```